# Getting Error: Object reference not set to instance of an object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

Hi i have two Mappings:

Ansprechpartner-Mappingfile:

```
<class name="Book.Doa.Ansprechpartner, Book.Co" table="ANSPRECHPARTNER">
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="foreign">
    <param name="property">Parent</param>
  </generator>
</id>

<property name="AnsprechPartnerName" length="20" column="PARTNER"/>
<property name="KonfStandort" length="20" column="KONFERENZSTANDORT"/>

<one-to-one name="Parent"
        class="Book.Doa.Gebaeude, Book.Co" constrained="true"/>
```

Ansprechparter.CS:

```
public class Ansprechpartner : DomainObject<long>
{
    public virtual string AnsprechPartnerName { get; set; }
    public virtual string KonfStandort { get; set; }
    public virtual Gebaeude Parent { get; set; }

    public Ansprechpartner()
    {
    }
    public Ansprechpartner(

        string ansprechpartnername,
        string konfstandort,
        Gebaeude parent
        )
    {
        AnsprechPartnerName = ansprechpartnername;
        KonfStandort = konfstandort;
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

and

Gebaeude-Mappingfile:

```
<class name="Book.Doa.Gebaeude, Book.Co">
    <id name="ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">GLOBALSEQUENCE</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="Bezeichnung" not-null="true" length="64" />
    <property name="Standort" column="Konfstandort" />

  <one-to-one name="Partner" lazy="false" cascade="all" fetch="join" outer-join="true"
   class="BookIt.Domain.Ansprechpartner, BookIt.Core"  />

</class>
```

Gebaeude.CS:

```
     public class Gebaeude : DomainObject<long>
    {

        public virtual string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
        public virtual string Adresse { get; set; }
        public virtual Stadt Stadt { get; set; }
        public virtual string Plz { get; set; }
        //Konferenzstandort ggf. unten noch hinzufügen.
        public virtual string KonfStandort { get; set; }

        public virtual Ansprechpartner Partner { get; set; }


         ......
}
```

They have a one-to-one relationship.

I try to get the value "AnsprechPartnerName with :  `room.Etage.Gebaeude.Ansprechpartner.AnsprechPartnerName`

But i always getting Error: `Object reference not set to instance of an object`

Why is that? what iam doing wrong on that part. My other mapping are working perfect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to map correctly over two tables in hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369389/how-to-map-correctly-over-two-tables-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means that you are trying to access a property of an object which is null. It does not imply that there is something wrong with your mapping, and there is no reason for us to think mapping is the problem based on data you provided.

Use a debugger and break on expression you mentioned (`room.Etage.Gebaeude.Ansprechpartner.AnsprechPartnerName`) and check if each property is set.

Is `room` not `null`?

Is `room.Etage` not `null`?

Is `room.Etage.Gebaeude` not `null`?

If one of them is not set, check in your database if data actually exists. Only then can you assume that problem is with your mapping.

Comment: room is not null, room.etage is not null, room.etage.gebaeude is not null. I thin Ansprechpartner.Ansprechpartnername is null. But i dont know why, because there are value in the database7