# How to map correctly over two tables in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two Mapping files. Building and ContactPerson. Each Buildung has one ContactPerson. So i have done a one-to-one relationship

In Building i have the column "Meetingplace" and in Contact i have the columns "Meetingplace" and "ContactpersonName"

In Contact i assign a Contactperson to a Meetingplace.

For example: Meetingplace in Building is Germany. Now in Contact i assign a Contactperson to  Meetingplace Germany.

Contact:

Here are my Mappingfiles

```
    <class name="Book.Doa.Contact" table="Contact">
<id name="ID">
  <generator class="foreign">
    <param name="property">Parent</param>
  </generator>
</id>

<property name="Contact" length="20" column="Contactperson"/>
<property name="Meeting" length="20" column="Meetingplace"/>

<one-to-one name="Parent"
        class="Book.Doa.Building" constrained="true"/>
```

Building:

```
 <class name="Book.Doa.Building">
    <id name="ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">GLOBALSEQUENCE</param>
        </generator>
    </id>


    <property name="Standort" column="Meetingplace" />

  <one-to-one name="Partner" lazy="false" cascade="all" fetch="join" outer-join="true"
   class="BookIt.Domain.Contact, BookIt.Core"  />

</class>
```

My problem ist that iam geeting alwas the Error:

```
Object reference not set to instance of an object
```

if i use room.Building.Partner.Contact to get the Contactperson for Meetingplace in Building.

There are values in the Database so i dont know why iam getting that error. What iam doing wrong?
The Questions is how can i get the ContactPerson for the Meetingplace in Bulding?

Please Help!
.

Comment: I've seen your German version, and could not find out what is wrong. But this translated version seem to be more broken. E.g. `room.Building.Contact` ... cannot work because your mapping says: `Building.Partner`. Could you show C# mapping? and the query you call resulting in null exception, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy = true as follows and it might work because I was facing same type of problem and it worked.

```
  <one-to-one name="Partner" lazy="true" cascade="all" fetch="join" outer-join="true"
   class="BookIt.Domain.Contact, BookIt.Core"  />
```

If solution does not work could you please turn on show_sql and let us know the result in case of lazy = false and lazy = true